# Turn enum into class with constants

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there an IntelliJ refactoring allowing to automatically turn an enum into a class, thus transforming its enum values into `static final` fields?

I can't seem to find anything about it, I only find stuff about extracting constants but not what I'm looking for.

#### Example of what I'm looking for

For instance, I'd like to turn an enum like this one:

```
public enum Planet {

    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters

    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    // getters here
}
```

Into a class like that:

```
public class Planet {
    public static final Planet MERCURY = new Planet(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6);
    public static final Planet VENUS = new Planet(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6);    
    public static final Planet EARTH = new Planet(5.976e+24, 6.37814e6);    
    public static final Planet MARS = new Planet(6.421e+23, 3.3972e6);    
    public static final Planet JUPITER = new Planet(1.9e+27, 7.1492e7);    
    public static final Planet SATURN = new Planet(5.688e+26, 6.0268e7);    
    public static final Planet URANUS = new Planet(8.686e+25, 2.5559e7);    
    public static final Planet NEPTUNE = new Planet(1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms    
    private final double radius; // in meters

    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    // getters here
}
```

#### If you wonder why someone would want to do this...

- if the enum shouldn't have been an enum in the first place (and for whatever reason someone declared it as such)
- to make it extend another class
- to fetch the enum values from a database instead of hardcoding them in the declaration (although I have to admit that in this case we just need to delete all the enum values and change the `enum` keyword into `class`, no need for such a complex refactoring)

*Note: the reason why someone would make the change is off-topic of course, please avoid discussing about it in this thread.*

Comment: you could show us a code example of what you mean. Before/After

Comment: May be it would be better to transform them to interface?

Comment: @RomanC Not really, because it is a complex Java enum, using the class quality of an enum (with constructor, methods and such), not just a list of values.

Comment: @Blundell Will do, I'm building a code example.

Comment: What's the point? An enum is already a class. If you want to allow additional instances of the enum class, you could extract its methods to an interface or abstract class, but still use the enum.

Comment: @JBNizet An enum can't extend an abstract class, can it? I want to do this because my class being an enum makes the automatic serialization of it too simple (just the constant name) and I want to turn it into a regular Java bean to make the serialization contain all its properties as a class.

Comment: @JBNizet And now, I'm also just curious as to whether this refac exists. Maybe some people want the enum to extend a class, so they have to turn it into a class, or maybe people before you misdeclared it as an enum where really it should not be, and you want to refactor it. I can think of multiple use cases where this would be useful.

Comment: AFAIK there's not, but you could probably leverage the multiline edit (see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/multicursor.html) or some regex replace. Note that I would advise against this "refactoring", you can probably use a custom "serializer" to get what you want keeping the enum

Comment: You're right. I spoke too fast. An enum can't indeed extend an abstract class.

Comment: @JBNizet Also, if I want to allow additional instances of my enum, why would I bother with convoluted stuff such as creating a parent interface etc, while the proper intent is to have a class in the first place?

Comment: You could says that for any interface. You define an interface to establish a contract for implementers and users, and some implementations of that interface can be an enum.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you on this reason to use an interface between your class and your users. But before that, you were saying I should create an interface for my users to create their own class copying my exact enum implementation just to create new instances. The point of my enum is to define a finite number of instances for a class. If I don't want this, I'll just create a class myself, and remove the enum. Whether or not I use an interface to offer the possibility of custom -probably *different*- implementations is another topic.

Comment: @Joffrey: I would only say that if there were a way to refactor your design to allow the use of an enum class rather than a regular class, you should do it, most especially if the enum were to be part of an exported API.  The security issues that are solved by enums make them worth the cost (and you get the iron clad guarantee by the JVM that your constants will be properly instance controlled).  Most Java enums *should* be rich enum types (with fields, methods, constant-specific methods, etc.); the fact that yours is rich doesn't mandate that it should be a regular class.

Comment: @scottb I completely agree with you, but all of this is off-topic. The discussion here is not about whether or not my enum should be turned into a class, but how to do so when it is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a link to it. But there is/has been talk of Java 9 or 10 having enum classes not inherit from the `Enum` class(Which all 'enums' are "just classes that extend Enum automatically hiddenly"(not a quote, but an easy way to think of them.)). Thereby allowing `extends` to work properly. I think it was even discussed for Java 8, but put on the back burner over finding more rock solid impl. of lambda, etc.

So I wouldn't be surprised if in the future it happens that you can extend enums.

---

Edit:

(Thought this was in here, but wasn't paying attention to my last previous edit.)

I've done this exact thing, and just used the "Replace" functionality within Notepad++, Kate, Eclipse (whatever editor I'm using at the time) or I used  gnu's awk command to do string manipulations. (I've done operations like this a lot. With a variety of means) Once you learn some basic Regular Expression, it is quite easy to manipulate string files like this.

For example you'd replace (within 'selection only' of top lines, if within an IDE/editor)

1) `<tab or 3/4 spaces>` with `public static final Planet`

2) `(` with `= new Planet(`

3) change the word `enum` to `class`

And you're done.

Comment: I'm doubting it (with the possible exception of extending abstract classes).  Regular classes are expected to be dynamic run-time moieties that are instantiated at need.  What good could it possibly do to have enum instances that are, by definition static, fixed, and immutable,  be child instances of regular classes?  The chief benefit of making enums not be `Enum<myEnum>` would be that they might play better with generics.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but this should be in the comment section as it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry, added "answer part", that I thought was already there, but must have messed up and not finished it properly.

Answer (score 1):

As @RC. said, it looks like there is no such refactoring feature at the moment.

I ended up using [multicursors](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/multicursor.html) and typing stuff manually as suggested.